# jboss server throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xml.sax.InputSource

Tags: java, xml, jboss

im trying to run joranConfigurator from a startup bean like this

```
private void configureLogBack() {
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

        try {
            File f = new File("mypath/loggerConfiguration.xml");
            JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
            configurator.setContext(context);
            // Call context.reset() to clear any previous configuration, e.g.
            // default
            // configuration. For multi-step configuration, omit calling
            // context.reset().
            context.reset();
            //configurator.doConfigure(System.getenv("obphm.logPath"));
            configurator.doConfigure(f);
        } catch (JoranException je) {
            // StatusPrinter will handle this
        }
        StatusPrinter.printInCaseOfErrorsOrWarnings(context);
    }
```

and im getting this exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xml.sax.InputSource
```

this is for logback, im not using logback.xml because the project architect told me he wants to do it this way... i did some research and apparently i have two conflicting xml api jars... is there a way to fix this without removing the other jar (partly because i dont know which other jar is conflicting)??

this is slf4j

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.slf4j.v175">
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar"/>
            <!-- Insert resources here -->
        </resources>

        <dependencies>
            <module name="ch.qos.logback"/>
        </dependencies>
    </module>
```

this is the logback

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="ch.qos.logback">
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="logback-classic-1.1.1.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="logback-core-1.1.1.jar"/>
            <!-- Insert resources here -->
        </resources>

        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.slf4j.v175"/>
        </dependencies>
    </module>
```

Comment: @helderdarocha thanks for the edit, didnt catch that when typing!

Comment: @amitsalyan well theres the logback jars that I have added because I'm using logback as the logging interface and that's where the exception is being thrown --- I added the logback module myself

Comment: @amitsalyan yes I can show them, and yes I'm using slf4j-api- added them

Comment: @amitsalyan I see, how did you know it uses sax? because of the logback module? (I'm assuming that's where it came from). How would I go about using an external jar? add it to the ear/lib folder? -- or add it to the classpath?

Comment: ok will try that and let you know what happens

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by removing the custom logback/slf4j modules I made and bundling up the required jars in the ear file. ALso fixed my jboss-deployment-structure.xml to include a main deployment in addition to the subdeployments I had listed